# Приведение типов в Java

Tags: java, android, массивы, list

Познаю ООП и Java на примере андроида. Столкнулся с проблемой, которую постарался описать. Прошу вашей помощи, гуру Явы!

Есть такой набор классов: модели круг и сфера, которые наследуются от общей  абстрактной модели EntityModel. Для каждой модели будет свой адаптер, все адаптеры моделей наследуются от абстрактного адаптера.

```
abstract public class EntityModel{}
class Circle extends EntityModel{}
class Sphere extends EntityModel{}

abstract public class EntityArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter{
   protected List<? extend EntityModel> items;
   public EntityArrayAdapter(List<? extend EntityModel> items){
      this.items = items;
   }
}
public class CirclesArrayAdapter extends EntityArrayAdapter{
   public B(List<Circle> circles){
      super(circles);
      this.items = circles;
   }
   public void run(int position){
      Circle p = this.items.get(position);
   }
}
```

В классе `CirclesArrayAdapter` всё хорошо до момента

```
Circle p = this.items.get(position);
```

Здесь IDE мне подсвечивает следующее:
[image]

Как мне решить проблему, что бы в каждом адаптере не создавать свойство items?

Comment: как реализовать - не скажу, но объясню, почему возникает такая ошибка...    
Каждый круг является EntityModel, но не каждая EntityModel является кругом.    
То есть в строчке с ошибкой вы пытаетесь присвоить более конкретному классу более абстрактный.    
И компилятор говорит что-то в роде этого "Чувааак! Не факт, что this.items.get(position) будет Circle! Там может быть и что-то другое!"

Comment: То же самое вы можете наблюдать, когда получаете вьюхи в активити при помощи findById().    Эта функция возвращает View, от которого наследуются все конкретные вьюхи. И Java требует приведения типа View к, на пример, TextView...

Comment: @metalurgus - спасибо за подсказку! ;)

Comment: @vkovalchuk88 - Прошу прощения... ![][1]

[1]: http://i.imgur.com/pzrPbms.jpg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проблема решена, спасибо [@metalurgus](/users/3997/metalurgus)

```
Circle p = (Circle) this.items.get(position);
```